# Musixtex strange bar positioning

Tags: musixtex

I wonder if anyone can please help me with this - I'm relatively knew to MusixTex.

I'm trying to construct scales using a For Each loop. The trouble is, that when I do so, the bar positioning seems to be shifted up - i can't tell why. The top picture shows what the extract should look like, and the one below shows what i actually get. Is it not possible to produce MusixTex programatically like this?

Thanks for any assistance.

```
    \begin{music}
    \Largemusicsize
    \instrumentnumber{1}        % a single instrument
    \setname1{}
    \setstaffs1{1}              % with one staff
    \generalmeter{\meterfrac44} % 4/4 meter chosen
    \nobarnumbers
    \generalsignature{2}            % Two sharps
    \startpiece 
        \notes
        \foreach \scalenote [
            evaluate={
                \noteletter={"N","a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v"}[\scalenote+2];
                \isendbar=int(mod(\scalenote,4));
            }] in{1,...,7}{
            \qu{\noteletter}
            \ifnum\isendbar=0 {
                \en\bar
                \notes
            }
            \fi
        }
        \en
    \endpiece
\end{music}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it's a problem of space in the code, but I couldn't pinpoint it.

This seems to work as you'd like to:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{musixtex}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\tl_const:Nn \c_stephen_notelist_tl {abcdefghijklmnopqrstuv}
\int_new:N \g__stephen_scale_start_int

\NewDocumentCommand{\makescale}{m}
 {
  % #1 is the starting point in the list of notes (1=c)
  \int_gset:Nn \g__stephen_scale_start_int { #1 }
  \int_step_function:nnN { 1 } { 7 } \stephen_scale:n
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \stephen_scale:n
 {
  \exp_args:Ne \qu { \tl_item:Nn \c_stephen_notelist_tl { \g__stephen_scale_start_int+#1+1 } }
  \int_compare:nT { \int_mod:nn { #1 } { 4 } == 0 } { \en\bar\notes }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{music}
  \Largemusicsize
  \instrumentnumber{1}        % a single instrument
  \setname1{}
  \setstaffs1{1}              % with one staff
  \generalmeter{\meterfrac44} % 4/4 meter chosen
  \nobarnumbers
  \generalsignature{2}            % Two sharps
  \startpiece 
    \notes
    \makescale{1}
    \en
  \endpiece
\end{music}

\begin{music}
  \Largemusicsize
  \instrumentnumber{1}        % a single instrument
  \setname1{}
  \setstaffs1{1}              % with one staff
  \generalmeter{\meterfrac44} % 4/4 meter chosen
  \nobarnumbers
  \generalsignature{-2}            % Two sharps
  \startpiece 
    \notes
    \makescale{0}
    \en
  \endpiece
\end{music}

\end{document}
```

You may need to add `\usepackage{xparse}` if you're not with the latest LaTeX kernel.

[image]

Comment: Oh, thank you very much. Yes, I thought it was something to do with spaces, but couldn't figure put how to solve. I will try your solution - thanks again.

Comment: @Stephen I fixed the issue of the repeated note.

Comment: thank you very much...even after reading the expl3 reference doc, i would never have figured out the difference between \c and \g assignments by myself. Thank you.